# Changing the text of the kerberos passwd prompt

Tags: kerberos, sles, passwd, sles11

We are running kerberos (krb5-1.7) on SLES 11 SP1.  Our users seem to have trouble changing their passwords with the password command.  They are confused by the initial prompt, and don't understand that it is first asking to "enter your current password" and not "enter new password".

e.g.,

```
user@host:~> passwd
Changing password for user.
Kerberos 5 Password:
```

Is there any way to change the default text for this prompt?  Or is it something that must be changed in the krb source and recompiled?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `[appdefaults]` section of `krb5.conf` add a `banner=foo`.